Efficiently apply maximal gradient on rows of a pandas dataframe
I want to apply a maximal gradient (in absolute value) on a Series of values. The problem is that the value of each row will depend on the value of the previous row.
if $f(t)$ represents my initial series, and $g(t)$ is my "smoothed" series, and I want to apply a max (absolute value) gradient of $a>0$, I want $$g(t+1) = g(t) + sign(f(t+1)-g(t))*min(a, |f(t+1)-g(t)|)$$
Exemple: I want to apply a maximal gradient of 1, in absolute value, from row to row, so if I have the following dataframe:
   B
0  0.0
1  1.5
2  2.3
3  2
4  0.4

I want to obtain:
   B    smoothed
0  0.0   0.0
1  1.5   1.0
2  2.3   2.0 
3  2     2.0
4  0.4   1.0

I can do it using 'iterrows()', but is there a method that would be more efficient for a large dataframe?

This is a standard approach that works well on large dataframes:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def smooth_series_with_gradient_limit(series, max_gradient):
    f = series.to_numpy()
    g = np.zeros_like(f)
    g[0] = f[0]  
    for t in range(1, len(f)):
        gradient = f[t] - g[t-1]
        g[t] = g[t-1] + np.sign(gradient) * min(max_gradient, np.abs(gradient))
    
    return pd.Series(g, index=series.index)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'B': [0.0, 1.5, 2.3, 2, 0.4]
})

df['smoothed'] = smooth_series_with_gradient_limit(df['B'], 1)
print(df)

which gives your expected output. Just to show the efficiency, here is an example with 1 million entries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time

def smooth_series_with_gradient_limit(series, max_gradient):
    f = series.to_numpy()
    g = np.zeros_like(f)
    g[0] = f[0]
    for t in range(1, len(f)):
        gradient = f[t] - g[t-1]
        g[t] = g[t-1] + np.sign(gradient) * min(max_gradient, np.abs(gradient))
    return pd.Series(g, index=series.index)

np.random.seed(0)
large_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'B': np.random.randn(1000000)  
})

start_time = time.time()
large_df['smoothed'] = smooth_series_with_gradient_limit(large_df['B'], 1)
end_time = time.time()

print(f"Execution time: {end_time - start_time:.2f} seconds")


Which is
Execution time: 3.33 seconds

Update
As was pointed out in the comments. `` g[0]shoould start at0regardeless off[0]```. Therefore, a more correct solution would be
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def smooth_series_with_gradient_limit(series, max_gradient):
    f = series.to_numpy()
    g = np.zeros_like(f)
    g[0] = 0  
    for t in range(1, len(f)):
        gradient = f[t] - g[t-1]
        g[t] = g[t-1] + np.sign(gradient) * min(max_gradient, np.abs(gradient))
    
    return pd.Series(g, index=series.index)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'B': [0.0, 1.5, 2.3, 2, 0.4]
})

df['smoothed'] = smooth_series_with_gradient_limit(df['B'], 1)
print(df)

which does give you
     B  smoothed
0  0.0       0.0
1  1.5       1.0
2  2.3       2.0
3  2.0       2.0
4  0.4       1.0


just adding a small correction g[0] should start at 0 regardless of what f[0] is since its a measure of gradient (technically it should not even matter, but it would minimize confusion)

@KaranShishoo Well observed there.
